# "Linked" and "Related" sidebars should include links to tag wikis

Tags: feature-request, tag-wiki, linked-questions

In many cases, I will answer a question and include a link to one or more other related questions or answers, and to tag wikis that provide extended details.

On the right hand-side of the question, there are sidebars for "Linked" and "Related" items.  Links to tag wikis do not show up there.  It would be quite nice if they did.